# xcode 5 tableview select while searching

Tags: xcode, search, select, tableview

I have a problem. I need to make a tableview selection while searching.

In normal mode it's ok, but when i search it does nothing. Code is simple

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.accessoryType == 0){
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

For select mode i use:

```
 -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text {
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
       isFiltered = FALSE;
    } else {
       isFiltered = true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search display controller overlays its own table view when it presents the search results. Therefore you need to check which table view is currently presented before reacting to a table view tap.

Here's how you can determine that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    // it's your "real" table view
} else {
    // search results table view
}
}
```

There's a demo project on GitHub which shows this in context in a working project: https://github.com/versluis/TableSearch2014

Comment: Doesn't work(((
Used simple test code to check anyway
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

Comment: Take a look at my demo project - I've just updated the answer with a link to it.